# Heroku "Request Interrupted" error when using Alamofire

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, swift, heroku, alamofire

I am using Alamofire to make HTTP request that return JSON from a Rails App running on Heroku.

When making an HTTP GET call, I get this NSError client side:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The operation couldn’t be completed
(NSURLErrorDomain error -1005.)
" UserInfo=0x1700e6a00 
  {
   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://********.herokuapp.com/api/workouts.json,
   NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://********.herokuapp.com/api/workouts.json,
   _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, 
   _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-4, 
   NSUnderlyingError=0x17025c920 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -1005.)"
  }
```

Error -1005 is a `kCFURLErrorNetworkConnectionLost`.

In the Heroku logs I get:

```
heroku[router]: sock=client at=error code=H18
desc="Request Interrupted"
method=GET path="/api/workouts.json" 
host=********.herokuapp.com 
request_id=826f4f74-a497-4462-a70b-cc5d352ef7b4
fwd="162.246.8.76" 
dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=0ms status=503 bytes=0
2015-01-15T03:30:15.428551+00:00 app[web.1]: 
Started GET "/api/workouts.json" 
for 162.246.xxx.xxx at 2015-01-15 03:30:15 +0000
```

The important part to notice is the `sock=client` which means that the request was interrupted at the request of the client.

Other endpoints such as `sign_in` and `sign_up` return `200 OK` with the expected payload.  So the Rails App is working on other endpoints.

Also, note that curl works as expected on the command line:

```
curl -X GET 'https://********.herokuapp.com/api/workouts.json?email=****&token=****'
```

Comment: Any success with this? Seems like I am having exactly same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it'll help somebody: in my case, I was sending an empty dictionary as parameters, by mistake:

```
var dictParams      = [String: String]()

Manager.sharedInstance
        .request(.GET, "\(K_API_MAIN_URL)\(k_API_XXXXXX)?access_token=\(strToken)", parameters: dictParams, encoding: .JSON)
```

Solution was to send nil instead of the above dictParams.

```
Manager.sharedInstance
        .request(.GET, "\(K_API_MAIN_URL)\(k_API_XXXXXX)?access_token=\(strToken)", parameters: nil, encoding: .JSON)
```